# permutation and combinations football score

Tags: java

Write a program that determines whether or not a positive integer is perfect. Your program identify

and display all of the perfect numbers between 1 and 10,000.
Write a program that reads an integer from the user. If the value entered by the user is less than 2

then your program should display an appropriate error message. Otherwise your program should

display the prime numbers that can be multiplied together to compute n, with one factor appearing

on each line. For example:

```
 0-0, 1-0, 2-0, 2-1
 0-0, 0-1, 1-1, 2-1



{
int m, n;
cout<<"Enter the finals scores of both teams";
cout<<"\nenter the score for team m :";
cin>>m;
cout<<"Enter the score for team n :";
cin>>n;
if  (m < 0 && n < 0){

        cout<<"score can't be negative";
        cout<<"\nenter the score for team m :";
        cin>>m;
        cout<<"Enter the score for team n :";
        cin>>n;
    }
else{
        int k=0;
        if (n==0){
            for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++){
                for (k; k <= n; k+=1){

                    cout<<j<<"-"<<k<<",\t";
                }
                k--;
            }
        }
        else if(m==1 && n==1){

            int i=0;
            int k=0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++){
                for (k; k <= n; k+=1){

                    cout<<j<<"-"<<k<<",\t";
                }
                k--;
            }
            cout<<endl<<endl;
            for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++){

                for (i; i <= m; i+=1){

                    cout<<i<<"-"<<j<<",\t";
                }
                i--;
            }
        }
        else {
            int i=0;
            int k=0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++){
                for (k; k <= n; k+=1){

                    cout<<j<<"-"<<k<<",\t";
                }
                k--;
            }

            cout<<endl<<endl;
            for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++){

                for (i; i <= m; i++){

                    cout<<i<<"-"<<j<<",\t";
                }
                i--;
            }               
        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, `if  (m < 0 && n < 0){` should be `if  (m < 0 || n < 0){`.

Comment: You don't really need all this `if/else if/else`, all you need is 2 nested for loops for any combination of `m`, `n`.

Comment: @DanialKhan Is your debugger broken actually?

Comment: i dont know i didnt use debugger i dont know how to use i m beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer to use recursion, If you don't know recursion read that first

```
void print_goals(int m,int n,int i,int j,string s)
{
    if(i == m && j == n)
    {
      cout<<s+char(48+i)+'-'+char(48+j)<<endl;
      return;
    }
    if(i<=m)
    print_goals(m,n,i+1,j,s+char(48+i)+'-'+char(48+j)+',');
    if(j<=n)
    print_goals(m,n,i,j+1,s+char(48+i)+'-'+char(48+j)+',');



}
```

call it as `print_goals(5,2,0,0,"");`
where m=5 and n=2

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ambika's answer, let me hint you to some problems with your io handling:

First at all, that's the simple and harmless part, in an if-else clause, either the if or the else block is executed, but never both (unless using some dirty goto hacks...).

So there is not much sense in asking the user for 'm' and 'n' within the if block again - so either don't do it (just leave `cout << "score can't be negative";`, or remove the else:

```cpp
if(m < 0 || n < 0)
{
    //...
}

print_goals(m, n, 0, 0, "");
// using Ambika's solution already...
```

But then consider that the user could have entered bad values *again*:

```cpp
while(m < 0 || n < 0)
// ^  instead of if!
```

Now the more serious problem (and it potentially gets *really* serious if you use the while suggested above):

Imagine, the user of your program enters – instead of a valid number – an invalid value, e. g. by accidentially hitting a letter key (`s7`). `cin >> n` cannot read an int then and the stream's fail bit will be set. In consequence, reading from cin subsequently will fail immediately without modifying m or n. Try it with the suggested while above and enter first `-1` and then `hello` – and be prepared to break the program with ctrl-c!

Solution: Either use cin's getline() right from the start and parse the string then, or reset the fail bit, as shown below:

```cpp
std::cin >> n;
if(std::cin.fail())
{
    // reset the fail bit
    std::cin.clear();
    // important: discard the invalid input!
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    // now we are prepared to read the input again
}
```

Have this within a loop, and you are fine. You might want to pack this loop into a function or have it within an outer loop for not duplicating the code; both solutions solve, too, another small problem concerning usability only: You always asked for both values, even though the first one could have been valid already. I'm coming up with the double loop variant:

```cpp
int result[2];
char c = 'm';
for(int& n : result)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        std::cout << "enter the score for team " << c << ": ";
        std::cin >> n;
        if(std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "invalid input" << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::string s;
            std::cin >> s;
        }
        else if(n < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "score can't be negative" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    c = 'n';
}
```